# Gps not registering

Tags: pokemon-go

I have a poke stop and a gym in my neighborhood, but my app has been telling me they are too far away, when I am right by them. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Have you been GPS spoofing or trying to cheat in any other ways?

Answer (score 1):

You have to be VERY close to a Pokestop or gym for Pokemon Go to register that you are close enough. Just being in the same neighborhood is not enough.